# Visual Studio 2019 - Code Map: disable "direct" reference from source class / dotnet core

Tags: visual-studio, .net-core, visual-studio-2019, code-map

I generated a code map for a .net core based project in VS 2019 (v16.0.0 Preview 4.0).

the problem: the code map 'creates' direct references to the source class

> Class 'A' forwards a reference for field1 to class 'B', B forwards it to C. In the map it looks like C directly accesses the information from B AND A directly (second doesn't happen in the code)

[image: see screenshot]

Is there a way to disable that the code map 'creates' these direct references from the source class?

Thanks for your help

Comment: Resharper finally did the trick for me. Looks like there is no way inside "Standard Visual Studio 19". Anyway - Resharper doesn't do these references from the source class. So problem solved in my case

Comment: tt_python, I'd greatly appreciate if you give a little pointer on where/how Resharper did the trick.